# error with jquery hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with 3 selects two are hidden and one at the beginning and depending on the selection appears one or the other, I use a. js called manipulation to create new rows to the table, also used an accountant to adding it to the id of the select and avoid the same call, the problem is that when I create a new row and not the change request does not mark bug only does nothing
Here is my code

```
code html

 <script>    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#estado").change(function () {
            if ($("#estado").val() == 2) {
                $("#sino").show();
                $("#sexo").hide();            
            }
            if ($("#estado").val() == 3) {
                $("#sino").hide();
                $("#sexo").show();
            }
    </script>
    <td>
    <select id="estado">
    <option value="1">Seleccione 1 opcion</option>
    <option value="2">Laboratorio</option>
    <option value="3">Datos Generales</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    //laboratorio
    <select name="sino" id="sino"style="display:none">
    <option value="1">Si </option>
    <option value="2">No</option>
    </select>
    datos generales
    <select name="sexo" id="sexo"  style="display:none">
    <option value="1">Masculino </option>
    <option value="2">Femenino</option>
    </select>
```

codigo .js

```
//manipulacion 
var cont=1
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#estado"+cont).change(function () {      
            if ($("#estado"+cont).val() == 2) {
                $("#sino"+cont).show();
                $("#sexo"+cont).hide();       
            }
            if ($("#estado"+cont).val() == 3) {
                $("#sino"+cont).hide();
                $("#sexo"+cont).show();
            } );
            var strNueva_Fila = '<tr>' +
'<td><label>Area Medica</label></td>' +
'<td><select id="estado' + cont +'"><option value="1">Seleccione 1 opcion</option><option value="2">Laboratorio</option><option value="3">Datos Generales</option><select></td>' +
'<td><select name="sino" id="sino'+cont'"style="display:none"><option value="1">Si </option><option value="2">No</option></select></td>' +
'<td id="columna1' + cont + '" ><select name="sexo'+cont'" id="sexo"  style="display:none"><option value="1">Masculino </option><option value="2">Femenino</option></select>'+
'<td><input type="button" value="+" class="clsAgregarFila"><input type="button" value="-" class="clsEliminarFila"></td>' +
'</tr>';
        cont++;
        var objTabla = $(this).parents().get(3);     
        $(objTabla).find('tbody').append(strNueva_Fila);      
        if (!$(objTabla).find('tbody').is(':visible')) {          
          $(objTabla).find('caption').click();
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.clsEliminarFila', function () {     
       var objCuerpo = $(this).parents().get(2);
        if ($(objCuerpo).find('tr').length == 1) {
            if (!confirm('Esta es el única fila de la lista ¿Desea eliminarla?')) {
                return;
            }
        }      
        var objFila = $(this).parents().get(1);      
        $(objFila).remove();
    });
            );
```

Comment: You haven't included enough of your code to assist. You should make a working jsFiddle or similar to show your issue, so others can help. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Look here is the complete code as html like. js just a matter of copying and pasting, if I understand what I'm trying to make is that when a new row agrege I make changes as the first, if you realize , when you add a row and does nothing.

html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jss/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="manipulacion.js"></script>
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#estado").change(function () {
            if ($("#estado").val() == 2) {
                $("#sino").show();
                $("#sexo").hide();            
            }
            if ($("#estado").val() == 3) {
                $("#sino").hide();
                $("#sexo").show();
            }
            });
            });
    </script>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <select id="estado">
    <option value="1">Seleccione 1 opcion</option>
    <option value="2">Laboratorio</option>
    <option value="3">Datos Generales</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <!-- //laboratorio -->
    <select name="sino" id="sino"style="display:none">
    <option value="1">Si </option>
    <option value="2">No</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <!-- //datos generales -->
    <select name="sexo" id="sexo"  style="display:none">
    <option value="1">Masculino </option>
    <option value="2">Femenino</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="button" value="+" class="clsAgregarFila"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

manipulacion.js

```
//manipulacion 
var contLin=1
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#estado"+contLin).change(function () {      
            if ($("#estado"+contLin).val() == 2) {
                $("#sino"+contLin).show();
                $("#sexo"+contLin).hide();       
            }
            if ($("#estado"+contLin).val() == 3) {
                $("#sino"+contLin).hide();
                $("#sexo"+contLin).show();
            }
}           );



});


$(document).ready(function(){
    //evento que se dispara al hacer clic en el boton para agregar una nueva fila
    $(document).on('click','.clsAgregarFila',function(){
        //almacenamos en una variable todo el contenido de la nueva fila que deseamos
        //agregar. pueden incluirse id's, nombres y cualquier tag... sigue siendo html

        var strNueva_Fila='<tr>'+
'<td><select id="estado'+contLin+'"><option value="1">Seleccione 1 opcion</option><option value="2">Laboratorio</option><option value="3">Datos Generales</option></select></td>' +
'<td><select name="sino'+contLin+'" id="sino"style="display:none"><option value="1">Si </option><option value="2">No</option></select></td>'+
'<td> <select name="sexo'+contLin+'" id="sexo"  style="display:none"><option value="1">Masculino </option><option value="2">Femenino</option></select><td>'+
'<td><input type="button" value="+" class="clsAgregarFila"><input type="button" value="-" class="clsEliminarFila"></td>'+
'</tr>';

contLin++;

        var objTabla=$(this).parents().get(3);


        $(objTabla).find('tbody').append(strNueva_Fila);


        if(!$(objTabla).find('tbody').is(':visible')){

            $(objTabla).find('caption').click();
        }
    });


    $(document).on('click','.clsEliminarFila',function(){

        var objCuerpo=$(this).parents().get(2);
            if($(objCuerpo).find('tr').length==1){
                if(!confirm('Esta es el única fila de la lista ¿Desea eliminarla?')){
                    return;
                }
            }


        var objFila=$(this).parents().get(1);

            $(objFila).remove();
    });



});
```